# How to fix "Elastigantt is not defined" error in Vue.js(laravel)

Tags: charts, vue-component

I installed one package in our laravel project i.e. npm install --save gantt-elastic, when i tried to implement in my Vue component it shows me error "Elastigantt is not defined" not able to identify the issue. please help me out from this.
https://vuejsexamples.com/elastic-gantt-chart-with-vue-js/

Answer (score 0):

update gantt-elastic to latest version :]
check examples folder to figure out how to integrate gantt in your project
https://github.com/neuronetio/gantt-elastic